# System.Net.Http conflict in Watson speech to text

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, visual-studio-2017, watson

When I build my project, I get the following warning:

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Warning MSB3243 No way to resolve conflict between "System.Net.Http, Version=4.1.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" and "System.Net.Http, Version=1.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a". Choosing "System.Net.Http, Version=4.1.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" arbitrarily.    SliqSpeechToTextCore    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets   1964

When I run, I get this exception when I try to instantiate the service by calling new SpeechToTextService()

> **System.IO.FileLoadException:** 'Could not load file or assembly 'System.Net.Http, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)'

My csproj is

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp1.1</TargetFramework>
    <PackageTargetFallback>dnxcore50;portable-net45+netcore45+wp8+wp81+wpa81;</PackageTargetFallback>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="IBM.WatsonDeveloperCloud.SpeechToText.v1" Version="1.0.0" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

I tried installing System.Net.Http from NuGet but it didn't help. I've found the most common solution for this type of problem is to add a dependentAssembly to the config. Is this solution relevant to .NET Core and if so what file would I edit?